# flash slideshow needed with special license

Tags: looking-for-a-script, flash, photo-gallery

I've been searching the web for an image flash slideshow similar to

http://www.dwuser.com/flashslideshow/

or

http://www.monoslideshow.com/

However, the main problem with those is the license.

for example

Monoslideshow may not be embedded in a template, desktop software application, content management system, **and / or online web service in a manner where Monoslideshow is replicated and / or used as a slideshow viewer for photos / videos and / or other media contributed by more than one party**

i'm working on a website that allows it's users to copy paste some html to their website/blog or wherever else they want and their images will be shown via the slideshow. (the images data / link targets would be supplied with xml)

The problem is of course the license.
I'm looking for similar image sideshows, with a few neat transition effects. Nothing too fancy but still slick looking.

Can i get some recommendations? seems like everywhere i look they all have the same license.

Budget is no more than $100 to $150

Comment: Is there a specific reason this needs to be flash?

Comment: not really, but they seem to have better looking transition effects available.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has come a long way as far as looks go, [here's a few good](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/projects/plugins?keywords=Slideshow&type=All&sort_by=changed) JQuery UI widgets that'll be easier to use with XML. Oh, and it's free. Oh, and it [has MIT/GPL licenses](http://jquery.org/license/). Oh, and it'll decrease load time / page weight.

Comment: link not working

Comment: The Plugins site is currently down for development... [look here](http://plugins.jquery.com)